# Can I make a call to a java class/method from a Trigger in a PostgreSQL (in Heroku)?

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, pljava

I need to make my PostgreSQL database execute a java class called by a trigger.

I read that you can install java on your PostgreSQL db, but to do this I might need superuser privileges, and don't know how to do this since PostgreSQL on Heroku doesn't offer this option.

Is there a way to do this?  Or perhaps a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to it with Notify in Postgres, but then you will have to poll the database periodically and get the notification.

- [Notify Postgres Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html)
- [Notify JDBC Documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/listennotify.html)